# how do you obtain a security certificate for a MS Office add-in?

Tags: .net, security, certificate, ms-office, add-in

Some people at the office feel uncomfortable having to disable "macro security for outlook add-ins" in order to get my add-in to work.

How do I obtain a security certificate for my add-in so that it loads in spite of the security settings currently in place? Is it worth the trouble? Does it cost a lot of money?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a code signing certificate for this.
Various Certificate Authorities release them:

1. http://www.symantec.com/verisign/code-signing/microsoft-authenticode
2. http://www.thawte.com/code-signing/content-signing-certificates/microsoft-office/index.html

These are just two, but there are many more.

Of course, you can create your own code signing certificate (actually two, a root certificate and a code signing cert). But the downside is you will need to install your root cert on every computer where you install the addin.